# What do you call the act of swiping a finger on your lips and blowing it to mimic a crazy person?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call the act of swiping a finger on your lips and blowing it to mimic a crazy person? I am referring to the act of blowing your finger with your lips and making the "BLBLBLBLBLBLBL" sound. Is there a word or phrase for it?

Comment: Not sure if there is word for this specifically, but related is  [blowing a raspberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_a_raspberry) .

Comment: A swiping motion is usually right to left or vice versa, like when you swipe the screen on a cell phone.

Comment: I think you're referring to  a forefinger being used as it it were a guitar pick that flicks (flips?) up and down on  puckered lips. I like the question if only because it is HARD to describe the action, and you did a good job describing the nonsense babble that is produced. Come to think of it, parents do this sound to newborn babies to make them laugh or smile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that there is an specific English word for this action. If there is, i have never encountered it that I can recall.

Answer (score 1):

Its called Batty Lip Burbling

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BattyLipBurbling

Answer (score 0):

I found some lists of words that denote sounds made by humans:

- [Noises made by the body](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/the-senses-and-sounds/noises-made-by-the-body)
- [Noises made by the mouth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/the-senses-and-sounds/sounds-made-by-humans-with-their-mouths/)

But they don't seem to include the sound you are looking for. (I believe it is what is heard in [this video titled "Brub brub brub brub brub"](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XIxqT96PUkQ)).